# Magento2, add to cart modal

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

On a successful trigger of `Add to Cart` button.

How we can get a modal like this picture?

Appreciate all your attention!
[image]

Comment: Hello @Linda do you need this in product detail page or in the listing page. If it is in listing page then I have a solution. For detail page I'll have to see that.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps

**Step 1** Implement below code end of file, in my case the file path is `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<?php $geturl = $this->getBaseUrl()."checkout/cart"; ?>
<div class="model-popup" style="display:none;">
    <div class="addto-msg">Thank you for purchase this product.</div>
    <button class="action tocontinue primary action-dismiss" type="button" data-role="action"><span>Close</span></button>
    <a href="<?php echo $geturl; ?>" class="action tocart primary">View Cart</a>
</div>
```

**Step 2** In success function approx line no 150 file path is `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

```
ajaxSubmit: function (form) {
        var self = this;

        $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
        self.disableAddToCartButton(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',

            /** @inheritdoc */
            success: function (res) {
                ............................
                ............................
                ............................
                /** add to cart popup modal **/
                var popup = $('.model-popup').modal({
                    modalClass: 'changelog',
                    });
                popup.modal('openModal');
                $('.modal-footer').hide();
                $('.modal-inner-wrap').addClass('checkoutpopup');
                $('.action-close').click(function() {
                  $('.modal-inner-wrap').removeClass('checkoutpopup');
                });
                $('button').click(function() {
                  $('.modal-inner-wrap').removeClass('checkoutpopup');
                });  
                /** add to cart popup**/
            }
        });
    },
```